# Mobile Web Button Documentation on Uber

Tags: uber-api

I notice that there is docuemntation for iOS and Android on how to set ride parameters on uber but not for mobile web. How would one set the ride parameters in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Buttons in a webpage on mobile would just be a link actually. So you would do something like this:

```
<a href="uber://?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&action=setPickup&pickup[latitude]=37.775818&pickup[longitude]=-122.418028&pickup[nickname]=UberHQ&pickup[formatted_address]=1455%20Market%20St%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2094103&dropoff[latitude]=37.802374&dropoff[longitude]=-122.405818&dropoff[nickname]=Coit%20Tower&dropoff[formatted_address]=1%20Telegraph%20Hill%20Blvd%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2094133&product_id=a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d">
    Get an Uber!
</a>
```

In that example, it's using a standard deep link so it won't work if the app is not installed on your user's device. If you are concerned about that, you can use a universal link instead:

```
<a href="https://m.uber.com/ul/?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&action=setPickup&pickup[latitude]=37.775818&pickup[longitude]=-122.418028&pickup[nickname]=UberHQ&pickup[formatted_address]=1455%20Market%20St%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2094103&dropoff[latitude]=37.802374&dropoff[longitude]=-122.405818&dropoff[nickname]=Coit%20Tower&dropoff[formatted_address]=1%20Telegraph%20Hill%20Blvd%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2094133&product_id=a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d">
    Get an Uber!
</a>
```

You can also use a `<button>` tag if you wish. Here's the documentation for this: https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/deep-linking-action-setpickup

You can copy paste this into your mobile browser directly to see it in action!

```
uber://?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&action=setPickup&pickup[latitude]=37.775818&pickup[longitude]=-122.418028&pickup[nickname]=AwesomePickup&pickup[formatted_address]=1455%20Market%20St%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2094103&dropoff[latitude]=37.802374&dropoff[longitude]=-122.405818&dropoff[nickname]=AwesomeDropoff&dropoff[formatted_address]=1%20Telegraph%20Hill%20Blvd%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2094133&product_id=a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d
```